# Windows XP SP3 and syncing to Windows Mobile 6.5

Tags: windows-mobile, windows-xp, activesync, rapi, wmdc

According to Microsoft Active Sync 4.5 will only work on [Windows XP SP2 and lower](http://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=15) and that Windows Mobile Device Center will only work on Windows Vista and above.

So where does that put XP SP3? I don't have an install of it hanging around to try it myself so I thought to ask, can Windows XP SP3 run Active Sync 4.5 or Windows Mobile Device Centre for the purposes of syncing to a Windows Mobile device?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ActiveSync works fine within WinXP SP3. The doc must be a typo or no one thought of getting a SP3 too.

Windows Mobile Device Center requires WinVista or higher and will also run within Windows 8 (requires to install .Net Framework 3.5 before WMDC install)..